# After npm install Material UI build error while importing the components in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

In a basic React Native after creating a blank project through EXPO installing all the basic dependencies like

```
npm install --save react-navigation (for navigation),
npm install @material-ui/core (for material-ui),
npm install react react-dom (for react and react DOM),
npm install (for its dependencies)
```

after the installation of the above items when I copy the whole button component same as given in the documentation of [MATERIAL-UI](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/).

and then at the time of 'expo start' command that is building command, the error is shown as below.[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P4bw.png)

Please help as you can!!!

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});

function TextButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.button}>Default</Button>
      <Button color="primary" className={classes.button}>
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button color="secondary" className={classes.button}>
        Secondary
      </Button>
      <Button disabled className={classes.button}>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button href="#text-buttons" className={classes.button}>
        Link
      </Button>
      <input
        accept="image/*"
        className={classes.input}
        id="flat-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
      />
      <label htmlFor="flat-button-file">
        <Button component="span" className={classes.button}>
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

TextButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(TextButtons);
```

Comment: The library you are trying to use is made for react and not react-native. Maybe this is causing the problem? You cant use react librarys or modules without modification on react native because there is no dom etc.

Comment: even without the react-dom package installation it is not  working the error is changed and showing as "Unable to resolve "react-dom" from "node_modules\@material-ui\core\ButtonBase\ButtonBase.js"
ERROR:-Building JavaScript bundle: error"

Comment: Yeah thats because you cant use a library or module made for react in react native. Because this is a native app and has nothing to do with web things like dom.

Comment: according to you i created a whole new blank  project and only installed the required react native dependencies and executed the the file for a build the error is same as the above attached screenshot

Comment: not really im just saying that the module u are using cant work in a react-native project because its made for normal react. For example u could use the this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-ui because this library is written for react-native